# Use the camera with android

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to use the camera with my App but when I push the button the application crashes and in the Android monitor appears the following message:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { 
act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE 
cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity } from 
ProcessRecord{bd3e6b7 4753:com.demonsystem.trackingticket/u0a94} (pid=4753, 
uid=10094) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
```

This is the code in my main activity:

```
btnCamara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(i,0); <-- here shows the error
                ocultar();
            }
        });
```

And these are the permissions:

```
private void checkCameraPermission() {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para la camara!.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 225);
        } else {
            Log.i("Mensaje", "Tienes permiso para usar la camara.");
        }
    }
```

These are the uses that I wrote in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

[image]

Comment: You need to check permission first.Then,do somthing you want to do.And use `onRequestPermissionsResult` to deal with the permission denied or granted.

Comment: So the way i Made the permission isn't the correct? I'm sorry i'm very new in android could you please how can i ask for the permission?

Comment: Use `https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher` and the demo also is Camera.It's easy for you.

Comment: I'm gonna check it thaks

Comment: Photos are harder than expected since is a common task anyone tends to think it should be trivial, but it is not, quite long and tedious actually. I recommend you this library https://github.com/fabian7593/MagicalCamera is the best for taking photos, takes care of permissions, take the photo or choose it from the gallery, it will save it as a file in the device, it will also register it in the gallery, has another features but that should get you started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
btnCamara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick (View view){
    if (hasPermissionUseCamera()) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, 0); 
        ocultar();
    }
  }
}

public boolean hasPermissionUseCamera() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 0);
            return false;
        }
    } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        return true;
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0: {
            if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(i, 0); 
                ocultar();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Access Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in `hasPermissionUseCamera` throw me a error and show me that is missing a ;

Comment: At what line ";" is missing?

Comment: before the `hasPermissionUseCamera() {` over the () and {, and in the return o that method (hasPermissionUseCamera) told that cannot return a value from a method void

Comment: First,getActivity() and getContext() replace with this.

Comment: And can you make screen where line numbers are visible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152265/discussion-between-levon-petrosyan-and-cesg-dav).

Answer (score 0):

Before fire the Image_Capture action just check , that your app has the permission or not.